# $N$ birds are distributed on a telephone wire

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory, approximation-theory, arithmetic-progressions

$N$ birds are distributed on a telephone wire that can fit a maximum of $2N$ birds. The spacings between birds form a sequence $S$. The minimum space between birds is $1$ unit. The sequence is ordered from least to greatest. For $N=4$ birds, one possible sequence is $S=\{1,1,3\}.$

Generate $2$ candidate step functions for $N=100,$ and provide a plot.

The sequence $S$ is a finite abstract counting function, which doesn’t count primes but may encode similar statistical properties as a finite sequence of primes.

I think analyzing these types of finite abstract counting functions is important because they can provide insights to finite distribution patterns over the integers.

Which function best approximates each of the $2$ candidates for $N=100$?

Comment: How is the *step function* defined for a sequence?

Comment: It would behave in a way like the prime counting function. so the values of the sequence $S$ would be the height at a given integer value. For example. At the first integer you'd have a height of $1$ because that is always the minimum space betwweent birds

Comment: Definition is not clear enough. In case of 4 birds there are 6 spacings between birds, not only 3 as in your example.

Comment: @z100:  I would assume the example is the spacing between successive birds, and is an ordered sequence, not a set.

Comment: Why would it behave at all like a prime counting function?  You have not specified any characteristics except all the spacings are positive integers and the total is not too large.

Comment: I want to edit the post such that the distribution is infinite and y=x is the closest approximation to the distribution, and to deduce an exact formula for the distribution. Since you already answered am I good to edit the question?

Comment: @Ross Millikan: so, spacing should be increasing, reducing a problem to a sum of at N non-increasing ntegers (successive spaces) equa.l to N. Example 1,1,3 means distribution (b.b.b...b) which is of the length 9 ...

Comment: It looks like you have two accounts, Ultradark, and z100.  The FAQ has instructions on merging them.  I do not appreciate not knowing that all the comments came from the same person.  Please think about your question and edit in all the restrictions, what you mean by $1,1,3$, how you are representing the sequences.  Go ahead and edit the question.  If my answer no longer applies, I will delete it.

Comment: Ultradark is my only account and I will edit the question to make it clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$S$ has to be a sequence (not a set-you need it ordered) of $N-1$ positive integers that sum to no more than $2N$, assuming the birds are allowed to be at the end of the wire.  There is nothing in the question to choose one such sequence, so you can pick any two.  $100$ is a lot of numbers to pick, so I would pick simple ones, like all $1$'s and all $2$'s, and call it good.  Finding an approximating function is easy for these.

Comment: Could I have more information, in terms of a plot? My question specifically asks that the answer includes a plot and uses N=100 birds.

Comment: I cannot settle for 1s and 2s

Comment: You have to define what is to be plotted.  Is it a dot on the line for where each bird is?  Can you see how to derive that from the spacing?  Is it the space between birds?  Both my examples then have a straight line for a plot.  If there are more restrictions on the sequence you should provide them.  On average the numbers have to be $2$ or less, so you have to have mostly $1$s and $2$s

Comment: For a case N=4:

(. . . . ) = {2,2,2,4,4,6}   ;           

(....    ) = {1,1,1,2,2,3}    ;       

(...    .) = {1,1,2,5,6,7}      ;    

Suggest binary.